# Opening a temporary buffer / scratchpad in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, text-editor

I often have to open a secondary editor outside of Netbeans in order to work on temporary bits of text outside of my project files. Is there a way to create temporary files in Netbeans without adding them to a project?

**File -> New** expects every file to be part of a project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, there is no such feature yet (I'm using 6.5).

You could include a folder in the Favorites window, and right click > New > Empty File from the folder, it won't be part of the project.

Answer (score 2):

I know this has already been answered successfully, but there is now a proper Netbeans plugin for this requirement: http://code.google.com/p/netbeans-scratchpad-plugin/  It works nicely for me and allows multiple scratchpads which can be handy.

Also note that the Copy/Paste History plugin which is available by default (with NB7 at least) is handy for this too.

HTH,
JD